# How to create layout type components in Ionic Framework

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I wanted to create a layout with background color orange and place one image and text in the left and right gravity in that layout. In native, I can create a linear layout and achieve the above requirements. But how to create a layout type component with background color and insert image in text into that component in Ionic Framework.

Comment: how about creating a div or class and using the CSS properties on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Untitled</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>text is here!</h1></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="assets/img/Screenshot (236).png"></div>
</div>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

here goes the style file AKA CSS

```
div{
  background-color:yellow;
}

back{
}

body{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

[image]